# Is the series $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty\binom{-1/2}{k} \frac{1}{k} $ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let us consider the series:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\binom{-1/2}{k} \frac{1}{k}
$$
I am not sure how to determine if this series is convergent or not. Can someone show me how?

Thanks

Comment: Leibniz criterion, for example.

Comment: It converges to $S=2\,\big[\ln2+\ln(\sqrt2-1)\big]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binomial coefficients $\binom{-1/2}{k}$ have alternating sign and decrease in magnitude. Hence Leibniz' criterion tells us that the alternating series

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{k}\frac1k$$

converges. We can also look closer at the binomial coefficients,

$$\binom{-1/2}{k} = \frac{(-1)^k}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k} \sim \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{\pi k}}$$

by Stirling's approximation, hence the series even converges absolutely.